# What are the 6 primary colors?

Tags: color, print-design, print-production, screen-printing

I'm working on a design and in the rules it says this:

> When designing/prepping final files, please be aware that there is a 6
>   color limitation on secondary and a 6 color limit on primary. Please
>   also don't overlap colors since printing is butt-fit with .003 stay
>   aways.

I tried reaching out to the person in charge (not a designer) and the only thing they told me was that only 6 colors could be used. This is probably a dumb question but how can I use 6 primary colors if there are only 3 (red, yellow, blue)? Also, what are the 6 secondary colors? Does this just mean that I can use any 6 colors I want (and possibly create more shades using halftones)?

Comment: A 6 color limitation is *not* the same as "6 primary colors".

Comment: This may not mean what  you think it means. They probably mean that you may only use 6 colors and 6 accents in designing to reduce human memory footprint.  Since most  desitns are lower than this its  a lot.

Comment: If you substitute "plates" or "print heads" or "inks" for "colours" it might begin to make more sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your previous question, you say it's about printing labels for beverage cans. These are usually printed in a single run on flat color ink printing machines, there are from 4, 6 and 8 colors. The six inks reference is maybe by the impression system used:

[image]

<sub>*[Read more here](https://yingrun.manufacturer.globalsources.com/si/6008852133126/pdtl/Canning-machine/1165225720/6-color-Printing-Machine-printing-the-surface.htm)*</sub>

About the six secondary colors it could be a second print run on the already printed cans.

This is another link with info about [8-color tinplate printing for can making/metal packaging](http://www.swkdsteel.com/show.asp?id=102).

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't make much sense. It only makes some sense if you are working with direct spot inks for, let's say silk printing, and they are referring to something like that.

> 6 colors could be used

---

Red, Yellow, and Blue are not primary colors. The primary colors are **Cyan, Magenta, and Yellow**.

**RYB** is an archaic color model (It is still used in some artist circles and for teaching kids). Since a more modern understanding of color is available, that model has been updated to **CMY-RGB** one.

---

You need to clarify this with the person in charge.

Comment: I'll try to reach out again and clarify. This is for a beverage label in case that helps any. Thanks for the information.

Comment: Red, Yellow, and Blue are primary pigment colours. There are different kinds of primaries depending on the application. CMY primaries were designated and are specified for a colour reproduction print process. (That's why they're called process colour primaries.) Red, Green, and Blue are primaries generally used for mixing light in a colour display. There are no "archaic" colour models in the true sense of the word.

Comment: Any color can be "primary" if those are the materials you have. Ocre and black, can be. Of course it is easier for a painter to use Red pigments instead of using magenta and Yellow. But the understanding of a color wheel is more mature than that. RGB are Light primary colors and CMY are Pigment ones.